# Can 'touch' work and 'mkdir' fail?

Tags: android, unix, mkdir, inode, terminal-emulator

Could there **ever** be a situation in which `touch` would work and `mkdir` would fail, within a directory.

I understand that both these calls involve writing to the `inode` of the parent directory. So if touch worked, doesn't it automatically mean that the inode is writable and hence, the `mkdir` *couldn't possibly fail.*

This was **Android** (I only heard a report, didn't actually see this case) and the commands were being run from the **terminal emulator**, in the `/system` directory (after requesting `su`), but that *shouldn't* make a difference IMO.

---

EDIT:
mkdir failed with `"permission denied"`

Comment: Was the name in use? `touch` doesn't mind if the file doesn't exist, in that case it merely updates the timestamps. `mkdir`, on the other hand, always tries to create a new directory, and loudly fails if that name is already taken by an existing file or directory.

Comment: @user4815162342 No other directories were in there. Tried several random names.

Comment: @user4815162342 mkdir failed with permission denied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of ways I can think of by which this could happen:

1) If you have reached the maximum number of sub-directories in a directory (typically around 32000), you will not be able to `mkdir`, but you will be able to `touch` a file.

2) If you are very low on disk space, you will not be able to `mkdir` because it requires 4K, but you will be able to `touch` a file.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I don't think either of those things happened. Is there no other way?

Comment: Also, why does mkdir use up more space?

Comment: an empty directory uses up more space than an empty file due to additional metadata.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you don't have write permissions on the parent directory? You would still be able to `touch` *existing* files in the directory if you own them or have write permissions on them. (However, calling touch on a file that does not exist will still fail since the directory is read-only.)

What's the output of `stat` on the parent directory and the `touch`ed files?

Comment: I need to check that. But if I didn't have write permissions on the parent, wouldn't the mkdir have also failed?

Comment: But you said the mkdir *did* fail. Or, if you meant touch instead, no you do not need write permissions on the parent to touch a file inside it. I just tested it out, myself, too.

Comment: Oops, I meant `touch`. I just tested it out, and when I remove write permission, from the parent, I **can't** touch a file within it, which makes sense, since the directory inode can't be written to. How is it letting you do that?!

Comment: Ah, I should've been clearer. You can touch *existing* files within the directory, since it only has to update their access times, but *not* create new files. I'll edit my answer to reflect this.

Comment: +1 That makes sense. But in this case, there was no existing file of that name, so I was writing a new file.

Comment: In that case, if it also isn't because of a reason @dogbane mentioned, I'm drawing a blank at the moment - try to get the output of `stat` on the directory and file. Alternatively, I hesitate to mention this, but is it at all possible that something happened in between `touch` and `mkdir` that would change the directory/file? Basically, have you been able to duplicate the behavior?

Comment: I'm trying to get the person who reported this to give me the output from stat. I have been unable to reproduce it so far, at my end though.